# Login no me redirecciona a admin_home

Tags: php, html

Saludos a todos espero me puedan ayudar con esta situación que ni chatGPT puede solucionar ya que me dice que todos los códigos están bien y están "redireccionando". La situación es la siguiente: tengo este código que he creado para poder hacer de login a la pagina web. He probado y esta haciendo la conexión a la base de datos, pero vuelve y redireccionar a login.php en vez de llevarme a admin_home.php o a alguna otra pagina según el rol del usuario. Verifiqué y esta funcionando el usuario ya que no me esta dando error de contraseña o usuario no encontrado. Si pongo mal la contraseña o pongo otro usuario si salen los errores.

```
// Incluir archivo de conexión a la base de datos
require_once 'conn.php';

// Verificar si se envió el formulario
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  // Obtener los datos del formulario
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  // Consultar la base de datos para verificar el usuario y contraseña
  $query = "SELECT * FROM afiliaciones_db.users WHERE username = ?";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->get_result();
  $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

  // Verificar si se encontró un usuario con las credenciales ingresadas
  if ($row) {
    // Verificar si la contraseña ingresada coincide con el hash almacenado
    if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
      // Redireccionar a la página correspondiente según el rol del usuario
      $role = $row['role'];
      switch ($role) {
        case 'admin':
          header('Location: admin_home.php');
          break;
        case 'district':
          header('Location: district_home.php');
          break;
        case 'local':
          header('Location: local_home.php');
          break;
        default:
          echo 'Rol de usuario desconocido';
          break;
      }
      exit();
    } else {
      echo 'Usuario o contraseña incorrectos';
    }
  } else {
    echo 'Usuario no encontrado';
  }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Sistema de Afiliaciones</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<section class="vh-100" style="background-color: #293683;">
  <div class="container py-5 h-100">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
      <div class="col col-xl-10">
        <div class="card" style="border-radius: 1rem;">
          <div class="row g-0">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-5 d-none d-md-block">
              <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/new-templates/bootstrap-login-form/img1.webp"
                alt="login form" class="img-fluid" style="border-radius: 1rem 0 0 1rem;" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-7 d-flex align-items-center">
              <div class="card-body p-4 p-lg-5 text-black">

              <form method="post" action="login.php">

                  <div class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 pb-1">
                    <i class="fas fa-cubes fa-2x me-6"></i>
                    <h1 class="mb-0">Sistema de Afiliaciones</h1>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" required />
                    <label class="form-label" for="username">Usuario</label>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" required />
                    <label class="form-label" for="password">Contraseña</label>
                    <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="true">
                  </div>

                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Iniciar sesión</button>

                </form>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

La parte de tu switch y las redirecciones parece estar bien, el problema podría estar en tu `$row['role']` una comprobación rápida que podrías hacer seria asignarle los roles a tu $role es decir `$role = 'admin';`, al desconocer la estructura de tu tabla `users` te pediria que verificaras que el campo role existe y tu user contiene alguno de los roles como string admin, district y local como valor

Comment: Lo intenté pero hizo lo mismo, si elimino role me dice rol de usuario desconocido